# Nuxt.js infinite-loading triggered immediately after page load

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, infinite-scroll

I'm using Nuxt.js with [Infinite loading](https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/old/#!/properties) in order to serve more list articles as the users scrolls down the page. I've placed the infinite-loading plugin at the bottom of my list of articles (which lists, from the very beginning, at least 10 articles, so we have to scroll down a lot before reaching the end of the initial list).

The problem is that as soon as I open the page (without scrolling the page), the infiniteScroll method is triggered immediately and more articles are loaded in the list (I'm debugging printing in the console "I've been called").

I don't understand why this happens.

```
<template>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-50">
    <subheader :feedwebsites="feedwebsites" />
    <div class="mdl-grid demo-content">
      <transition-group name="fade" tag="div" appear>
        <feedarticle
          v-for="feedArticle in feedArticles"
          :key="feedArticle.id"
          :feedarticle="feedArticle"
          @delete-article="updateArticle"
          @read-article="updateArticle"
          @write-article="updateArticle"
          @read-later-article="updateArticle"
        ></feedarticle>
      </transition-group>
    </div>
    <infinite-loading spinner="circles" @infinite="infiniteScroll">
      <div slot="no-more"></div>
      <div slot="no-results"></div
    ></infinite-loading>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import subheader from '~/components/subheader.vue'
import feedarticle from '~/components/feedarticle.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    subheader,
    feedarticle,
  },
  props: {
    feedwebsites: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return []
      },
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      feedArticles: (state) => state.feedreader.feedarticles,
    }),
    ...mapGetters({
      getInfiniteEnd: 'feedreader/getInfiniteEnd',
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    async updateArticle(id, status) {
      try {
        const payload = { id, status }
        await this.$store.dispatch('feedreader/updateFeedArticle', payload)
      } catch (e) {
        window.console.log('Problem with uploading post')
      }
    },
    infiniteScroll($state) {
      window.console.log('I've been called')
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$store.dispatch('feedreader/increasePagination')
        try {
          this.$store.dispatch('feedreader/fetchFeedArticles')
          if (this.getInfiniteEnd === false) $state.loaded()
          else $state.complete()
        } catch (e) {
          window.console.log('Error ' + e)
        }
      }, 500)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try to add v-if="feedArtickles" on your `main` tag, cause they are not loaded yet.

Comment: Tried but still working as previously exposed :(

Answer (score 1):

Put `<infinite-loading>` in `<client-only>` tag :

```
<client-only>
   <infinite-loading></infinite-loading>
</client-only>
```